# Deleting invisible/unused input fields in Orbeon form

Tags: forms, xpath, orbeon

We have the following situation:
We have one form (we’ll call it “first form” for easier reference) which, among other things, contains dropdown select-box from which the user has to select a number from 1 to 10. Based on the number the user has selected (e.g. 5), on the separate form - on a different page (we’ll call it “second form”) we show that many number of sections as visible (5 new sections in our example). For each of the 10 sections we have defined visibility condition through XPath expression which returns true or false based on the number the user has selected from the first form. Now, because second form contains all 10 sections it shows all of them in the DOM, but in our example only 5 are visible on the front end.
So the question is: Is it possible to have the 5 additional sections not render in the DOM structure at all and if it is, how to achieve this?

Comment: You'll have to tell us more about your context: are you using Form Builder or writing XForms by hand? How are you showing *n* sections, say 5 in your example? Are you creating 5 elements in your XForms instance, and using an `xf:repeat`? If this is what you are doing, you should really just have 5 "sections" in the DOM sent to the browser.

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick reply. We are using Form Builder for our forms. In our form we have 10 separate sections - not using `xf:repeat`. Each section has in it XPath expression (condition for it's visibility) e.g - `number(/path/to-some-number-in-the-first-form) > 2`. As I've said this all works, but we don't want to have all sections render in the DOM tree if they are not visible anyway.

Comment: We didn't want to use repeated sections because we have dependency from the first form and we couldn't find where to enter the above mentioned condition for each repeated section, i.e. we couldn't create the condition that would show only limited number of repeated sections based on the number entered on the first form.

Comment: Got it; I think that what you're asking for is covered by [request for enhancement #1117](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1117). But until this is implemented, as you noted, something will be found in the DOM for those non-relevant sections. Can I ask what your main concern is with having this in the DOM? Is it related to performance, or something else?

Comment: Well, yes, as it is noted in that link you posted, we don't want to have excess DOM nodes just sitting there :). Basically, everything that is said in that link you posted we wanted to avoid. Thank you again for your reply.

Comment: Understood, and I've added a +1 from you on that issue.